# Threads calling function in another class which returns data

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to understand the multithreading in c++. I am trying to call a function in another class using two threads as shown below. This function also returns the data.

**vmgr.h**

```
class VMGR{

public:
    int helloFunction(int x);
    
};
```

**vmgr.cpp**

```
#include"vmgr.h"
#include<iostream>

int VMGR::helloFunction(int x){

    std::cout<< "Hello World="<< x << std::endl;
    
    return x;

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "vadd.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>
#include<algorithm>
#include "vmgr.h"

using namespace std::chrono;


    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
        VMGR vm;
  
        std::thread t1(&VMGR::helloFunction, vm, 20);
        std::thread t2(&VMGR::helloFunction, vm, 30);
    
       t1.join();
       t2.join();
        
       
       return 0;
    }
```

My syntax of return values from a thread is not correct. Please help me with how to handle the return values. Thank you in advance.

Comment: consider this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: The easy way would be to use different objects (vm1 and wm2) and store the return value in a class member and the use them after joining. Otherwise, there are many way but I would highly recommande reading a book like **C++ concurrency in action** to have a better understanding as improvising on multithreading might cause hard to understand bugs if you are not familiar with the rules...

Comment: Thank you @Phil1970. I will read the book. I think, using using different objects might be easy.

Comment: It all comes down to this: What do you want to do with the return values?

Comment: Depends on how you want to use the values. Could be that storing the values in a vector guarded by a mutex and using a condition variable to inform the main thread about the presence of a result, but in different scenarios you may be better of using some other way of communicating back the results.

Comment: Thank you @selbie for your response. I am trying to make a  application, where different processes send data to manager to execute the data on an accelerator. To  handle multiple processes simultaneously, I am trying to parallelize the handling of different processes data using threads. Presently my application just stores different requests in a message queue and handle one request a time. I am trying to understand the steps to parallelize the application.

Comment: It will probably be more useful for you to invest some time in a good C++ textbook that explains how to use threads in C++, including passing data to/from threads using a wide variety of techniques -- mutexes and condition variables; promises and futures; etc... This will be a more productive way to learn one of the most advanced topics of the most complex general purpose programming language in use today; much more productive then asking one question at a time, on Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow isn't really designed to be a replacement for a textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple method obtaining results from the threads is using multiple pointers.

My simple solution follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std::chrono;

class VMGR {
public:
    void helloFunction(int x, int *res);
};

void VMGR::helloFunction(int x, int *res) {
    std::cout << "Hello World=" << x << std::endl;
    *res = x;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    VMGR vm;
    int outputs[2];
    std::thread t1(&VMGR::helloFunction, vm, 20, &outputs[0]);
    std::thread t2(&VMGR::helloFunction, vm, 30, &outputs[1]);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    for (auto n : outputs)
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

But, above is **too** simple code.
If your "hellofuntion()" have side effects, you must add synchronization codes.

Comment: One can say "std::cout << "Hello World=" << x << std::endl;" have side effects, already.